# Access update query change empty value into Null value

Tags: sql, ms-access

is it possible to use an access update query to change values into Null?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to insert text "**is null**" into field? Why?

Comment: No, I want to change the value of the field so that it is completely empty. Because there is a difference in Access between ““ (empty) and Null. So that I could use IsNull() to check for it. But I need it for a different reason.

Comment: Yes, can replace empty string with Null in UPDATE SQL. What have you tried? I always set text fields in table design not to accept empty string. Need to verify field is really holding empty string and not some other non-printing character.

Comment: Thanks, I tried different things with IsNull(), but never Null alone.

Answer (score 1):

If your values are actually empty strings, you can do

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = NULL WHERE myColumn = ''
```